# Web scraping oddsportal using R and SelectorGadget

Tags: r, api, web-scraping

I´m following this tutorial : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TPLMQnGw0Vk
And trying to scrape : http://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/england/premier-league-2014-2015/arsenal-west-brom-AyTNt38e/#over-under;2;2.50;0

The information I want is average odds above 2.5 goals, in this case its 1.5

```
library("rvest")

html = html("http://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/england/premier-league-2014-2015/arsenal-west-brom-AyTNt38e/#over-under;2;2.50;0")

html1 = read_html("http://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/england/premier-league-2014-2015/arsenal-west-brom-AyTNt38e/#over-under;2;2.50;0")

# I tried using both html and read_html, because I got that warning message. 

htmlSO = html_nodes(html1, ".aver .right:nth-child(3)") 

#.aver.... I got using SelectorGadget

#List of 0.
```

How can I get the data 1.50 stored?

Comment: Neither site generates a warning with `rvest::read_html`. Also, that page is dynamically generated. It reads [`http://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/england/premier-league-2014-2015/arsenal-west-brom-AyTNt38e/`](http://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/england/premier-league-2014-2015/arsenal-west-brom-AyTNt38e/) in via an XHR request.

Comment: If I use this webiste instead : http://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/england/premier-league-2014-2015/arsenal-west-brom-AyTNt38e/#over-under;2;2.50;0. And use selector gadget : .aver .right:nth-child(3). Trying to get the average value 1.5. I still get a list of 0

Comment: Because the site is dynamically generated. Use Developer Tools to find the right URLs to scrape or use RSelenium. You'll need to work to do your betting.